# Is the sort-order of table-valued-parameters guaranteed to remain the same?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2014, table-valued-parameters

I need to know if i need to add a sort-column to my custom table-type which i could then use to sort or if i can trust that the order of parameters remains the same even without such a column.

This is my type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[VwdCodeList] AS TABLE(
    [VwdCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

and this is one of the sql where is use it:

```
/// <summary>
///     Inserts all new WatchListCodes for a given watchlist
/// </summary>
public const string InsertWatchListCodes = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WatchListCodes]
   ([WatchListID]
   ,[VwdCode]
   ,[Sort])
 SELECT @WatchListID, VwdCode, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
 FROM @VwdCodeList;";
```

as you can see i'm using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the sort-column value.

Do i need to add also a sort-column to the table-type or is it guaranteed(documented) that it remains the same? It seems to work.

This is the ADO.NET code where  i use it:

```
SqlParameter vwdCodeListParameter = insertWatchListCodeCommand.Parameters.Add("@VwdCodeList", SqlDbType.Structured);
vwdCodeListParameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[VwdCodeList]";
vwdCodeListParameter.Value = WatchListSql.GetVwdCodeRecords(newVwdCodes, true);
int inserted = insertWatchListCodeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`GetVwdCodeRecords` returns `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` for an `IEnumerable<string>`.

---

Thanks all. If a future reader is interested to know how i've guaranteed the sort-order. I've modifed the table-type as suggested by adding another column:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[VwdCodeList] AS TABLE(
    [VwdCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Sort] [smallint] NOT NULL
)
```

The insert-sql is even simpler because the sort-column is passed in and not calculated:

```
public const string InsertWatchListCodes = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WatchListCodes]
   ([WatchListID]
   ,[VwdCode]
   ,[Sort])
 SELECT @WatchListID, cl.VwdCode, cl.Sort 
 FROM @VwdCodeList cl;";
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the method that returns the `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` used as value for the table-valued-parameter(omitted error-handling):

```
public static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> GetVwdCodeRecords(IEnumerable<string> vwdCodes, bool trimCode = true)
{
    short currentSort = 0;
    foreach (string vwdCode in vwdCodes)
    {
        var record = new SqlDataRecord(
            new SqlMetaData("VwdCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50), 
            new SqlMetaData("Sort", SqlDbType.SmallInt));
        record.SetString(0, trimCode ? vwdCode.Trim() : vwdCode);
        record.SetInt16(1, ++currentSort);

        yield return record;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good chances are, this depends on the table type definition. For example, defining a primary key on your table type has a decent chance of changing the order in which you get your records back. I would take a safer approach of adding another column to the table type, and setting it in your ADO.NET code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general: **There is no implicit sort order on any result set**.

The **only way** to achieve a **guaranteed sort order** is an **`ORDER BY` on the outer-most query**.

I'm sure you knew this already...

There is one [specialty with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...)` Read "General Remarks"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). But this is dangerous.

- The sort-order is only sure, if you are using a unique sort criterium in `ORDER BY`. You are using `SELECT 1`, which will not guarantee any sort order. This might work hundreds of tests and suddenly breaks...
- Any later action can destroy this sort-order. Just imagin you have a working function and - some months later - you use this function in a complex query.

I use this for example to create XML with a sure order, because within XML there is an implicit order given by position...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to add a column. SQL is a set-based language and sets are inherently unordered (admittedly, there are more than a few cases where SQL is kind of leaky about this).

If you want to use `ORDER BY` and you want to guarantee the results, you need to ensure that it's based on enough expressions based on the *data* within the table such that it uniquely defines the ordering. Here, you're ordering by a constant (and the warnings you receive if you just try `ORDER BY 1` here should be enough clue that its not going to work well) so there are no guarantees on what ordering is actually applied.

Comment: Thanks. But couldn't it be that a custom table-type that is used for table-valued-parameters is treated differently by sql-server? So that they actually guarantee the insertion order to remain the same. It would be useful. I know that the order isn't guaranteed normally and that a table has no "inherent" order. But a table-type that has a very short lifespan as parameter and could behave differently. But i guess there is no difference to a plain table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - at the point in time at which table-types were introduced, every experienced SQL developer was used to working with tables in which there is no inherent order. What, then, would be the justification for providing additional guarantees or development effort for these new objects, just so that they act differently? And if they did have this surprising new behaviour, you'd expect it to be highlighted in the documentation as part of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Same order is not guaranteed unless you do an explicit order by..

Below are some tests..

```
 create type numbes as table
 (
 num int primary key
 )


 DECLARE @nums AS numbes;  

 insert into @nums
 select row_number() over(order by(select 1)) 
 from
 master.sys.objects


 select Top 100* from @nums
```

and execution plan shows..

[image]

So below piece of code..

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
 FROM @VwdCodeList;";
```

may not get you same order every time,unless you mention explicit order by

Comment: Thanks. But couldn't it be that a custom table-type that is used for table-valued-parameters is treated differently by sql-server? So that they actually _guarantee_ the insertion order to remain the same. It would be useful. I know that the order isn't guaranteed normally and that a table has no "inherent" order. But a table-type that has a very short lifespan as parameter and could behave differently. In your example you're selecting from a plain table.

Comment: I too thought the same for table valued parameters,since they are readonly..But order by is not guaranteed for any result set,until you order by ..you may also want to check this article..

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: @TimSchmelter, We don't know... Even if we knew this, one should not rely on this order. With procedural approaches you tell the engine **how something is done**. But with *set-based* SQL Server you just tell **what you want**. The engine might solve it one or another way, this should not bother you at all... Just imagine, that your approach works great with short lists until you feed a very large list and the engine decides to go into parallelism... If your lists are short, you might hand in your parameters as XML. This is sorted implicitly...